# Prettier arrow parentheses around single line function body

Tags: javascript, prettier

I am using Prettier with AngularJs. I am having this small function:

```
this.resetForm = () => this.formData.email = this.user.email;
```

When saving, Prettier add parentheses around the function body:

```
this.resetForm = () => (this.formData.email = this.user.email);
```

I have not found anything in the settings to prevent this, so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://prettier.io: "An opinionated code formatter", "Has few options". If you choose an opinionated tool, don't be surprised if you don't get to have conflicting opinions :)

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case. Thank you for the help

Comment: Prettier maintainer here. This feature is by design — we want to make it obvious that you’re *assigning* (`=`) rather than checking for equality (`==` or `===`).

Comment: @JedFox is there a thread on this, as I'm really not sure how the parentheses help. To my eye, having parentheses makes it look more akin to `if (this.formData.email === this.user.email)` so actually makes it less obvious that there is an assignment

Comment: @JedFox this also happens for inequality checking. for me 
`const ratio = computed(() => segment === 'fabrics' ? 500 / 281 : 1)`
keeps getting changed to
`const ratio = computed(() => (segment === 'fabrics' ? 500 / 281 : 1))`. is there a fix for this?